# How do you access the fixture with MiniTest spec?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

```
describe Receipt do 
  describe 'invoice' do
    it 'is valid' do
      invoice = invoices(:invoice1)
    end
  end
end
```

How do you access the test fixture inside MiniTest Spec?
If I run the code from above I get 'undefined method invoice' even if it's working inside a TestCase class.

Thanks!